# C++ unresolved external symbol when returning factory function

Tags: c++, dll, factory

I try to return a factory function from a DLL. The DLL works with a class internally and exposes an interface (struct). When I do the very same thing, but with an integer instead of a pointer, it just works. But with the pointer, I can compile the DLL, but the linker gives me the error `error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) struct MyN::IClass * __cdecl MyN::getClass(void)" (__imp_?getClass@MyN@@YAPEAUIClass@1@XZ)`.
I used dependency walker to examine the DLL and it does in fact export the function in question (just without the `__imp_`).
**Before the comments go wild: Yes, I do include the `.lib` file.**
I am using MS Visual Studio 2013 Update 4. Please find below a rough sketch of what the situation looks like:

```
// File DLLPublicClass.h
#pragma once
namespace MyN
{
  struct IClass
  {
    ~IClass(){}
  }
}
```

```
// File DLLPrivateClass.h
#pragma once
#include "PublicClass.h"
namespace MyN
{
  class Class : public IClass
  {
    ~IClass(){}
  }
}
```

```
// File DLLPublicMain.h
#pragma once

#if defined EXPORTTEST_EXPORTS
#define ETAPI __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define ETAPI __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#include "DLLPublicClass.h"
namespace MyN
{
  ETAPI IClass *getClass();
}
```

```
// File DLLPublicMain.cpp
#include "DLLPublicMain.h"
#include "DLLPrivateClass.h"
ETAPI MyN::IClass *MyN::getClass()
{
  return new MyN::Class();
}
```

```
// File EXEMain.cpp
#include "DLLPublicClass.h"
#include "DLLPublicMain.h"
int main()
{
  MyN::IClass *TestC = MyN::getClass();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: is EXPORTTEST_EXPORTS defined for the dll project?

Comment: yes. If I call my DLL project ExportTest, EXPORTTEST_EXPORTS will be defined for the DLL. At least on MSDN it says so and Intellisense finds the define as well.

Comment: No, I did not. At the moment, I cannot find the exact page, but I got the lines from MSDN and they work. Intellisense does find the definition. When I open the header from the DLL, the import is greyed out. When I open the header from the EXE, the export is greyed out. Additionally the definition is written in purple which means it was found. If I change the name, the definition goes white.

Comment: Found the article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-en/library/ms235636.aspx

Comment: Perhaps this has to do something with name mangling because IClass lives in a namespace? Usually, I only export c-Functions and c-structs from my dlls via `extern "C"`.

Comment: Your code seems to work fine in my version of VS2013 update 4. I can replicate your exact error message if I don't link the LIB file of the DLL. I would do a complete clean/rebuild and make sure I'm using the correct version/location of the LIB file.

Comment: The `.lib` in this case is an import library.

Comment: @uesp: well, that's strange. I made a new project. And it worked. Hmm, strange things happen. Thank you all for the great help :)

Comment: Another thing to check if you are using the VS project preprocessor settings to set `EXPORTTEST_EXPORTS` is to make sure it is properly set for all configurations of the project(s).